Adjusting time for audio of HLS stream
Is it possible to adjust a value in the initialization section provided by EXT-X-MAP to adjust the timing of the audio during playback? For example, I'd like to shift the audio forward or backward by 1 second, so can I do that by adjusting a value in the initialization section rather than re-encoding all of the audio data?
